# Active Record getting PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: when permission exits for the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

We are using the Gem PaperTrail, so in postgres we have a table called `xxx.versions`.

Through rails consoles locally we try to query the db through the PaperTrail Object:
`PaperTrail::Version.first`

> PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied for relation versions
>   : SELECT  "versions".* FROM "versions"  ORDER BY "versions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

but if I access the table like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM xxx.versions limit 1")
```

a record set is returned.

This only happens when we try and connect to the db from our local machines.

If I run `PaperTrail::Version.first` from the rails console on one of the qa servers it connects just fine.

Other troubleshooting details:

- I have used the same credentials as the qa server and received the
  same results.
- On my local machine, I can query the DB from
  DataGrip/pgadmin just fine outside the rails project.

Comment: Lok into the PostgreSQL log and see what *actually* happens.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe we have done that as well and there it looks pretty much like the error we are seeing through the rails log even when we bump it up to debug_5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

- You use a different PostgreSQL user or database in both attempts.
- There is a different relation `versions` in another schema that is before `xxx` on the `search_path`.

Comment: the first one is not likely, we use only one database.yml in the application and it only has one connection for each env. The second I had not thought of... I'll look into it.

Comment: it was the second!, we had another schema in the search path with the same table name!